# The dash is a invalid syntax in the import settings

Tags: python

I have a problem with launching the code, the problem was

```
"File C:\Users\User\Something\main.py
 import color-utility
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Yes, name it `color_utility` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should use `import color_utility` instead of `-`.

Comment: This was fixed but.. it doesnt find the module when it is installed.

Comment: What does it say now? I mean, what module is it? Can you provide pypi.org link? @mtrtgrrn4er1 -> Just make edit on your question and add there necessary data.